# pseudocode - how to resize image to max size

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, pseudocode

quick Q here.

I have an image of dimensions $height and $width. The maximum sizes i want them are: $maxHeight = 200; $maxWidth = 120;

How can I resize the image if $height > $maxHeight || $width > $maxWidth ?

(assume there is a function setSizeForImage($newHeight,$newWidth))

(actually using imagemagick in php but i don't think there is anything specific to that)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep the width/height ratio,

```
$scale = min(
            $maxWidth / $img_width,
            $maxHeight / $img_height
        );
if ($scale > 1) {
    $scale = 1;
}

$new_width = $img_width * $scale;
$new_height = $img_height * $scale;
setSizeForImage($new_height,$new_width);
```

Comment: thanks :) looks so simple now i think about it haha could have worked that one out

Comment: glad to help :) i hope it fit your needs